# How to see invocation in Xcode

Tags: objective-c

I'have got an error in build.
Xcode return

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Do you know how can i launch build with -v to see invocation ?

Comment: this is very often happen to developers, but no one answer for it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get invocation for Xcode "clang" compile-time error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031963/how-to-get-invocation-for-xcode-clang-compile-time-error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Xcode click on 'View', 'Navigators' and 'Show Report Navigator' then click on the build that failed.  In the listing of the build steps you will see your 'use -v to see invocation' - to the right click on the disclosure icon (next to the error icon).

[image: Screenshot indicating where to click]Doing that will show the details of the linker invocation.

Of course, the actual problem is that you are building an executable without including the file that contains 'main'.  Usually one is created for you and automatically included - based on the target.  If you are making a target yourself; you'll need main() implemented somewhere.

Comment: The log navigator is generally the far-right icon in the icon list of the navigator (left) column, IIRC.

Comment: Tried it. Only got exactly the same information the compiler gave me when it threw the error... the same information that says `(use -v to see invocation)`. In other words, it's pretty clear this is not how to get the invocation.

Comment: Many times I face same error (user -v to see invocation) , but I couldn't understand WHERE and HOW to use the "-v" to see invocation !!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can add the -v to the "Other Linker Flags" field in the project settings. Doing so in a test project here yields the complete linker invocation:

[image: complete linker invocation]

[image: complete linker invocation]

when you add -v to "Other Linker Flags" you will get more information, this is the different between add before and add behind