# How to get invocation for Xcode "clang" compile-time error?

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, clang

I get a compile-time error in Xcode that includes this message

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This `-v` is evidently a command-line option. I've run into this message before and have always been at a loss as to what I can do about it and why it's included if I can't do anything about it.

How can I employ the option in Xcode to see the invocation?

Comment: The title of the question is wrong: this is a link-time error, not a compile-time error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the `-v` to the "Other Linker Flags" field in the project settings.  Doing so in a test project here yields the complete linker invocation:

```
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld"
 -demangle
 -dynamic
 -arch x86_64
 -macosx_version_min 10.8.0
 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk
 -o /Users/carl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/example-ewesimyvcwmjptdwzbkqoasrcppe/Build/Products/Debug/example
 -L/Users/carl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/example-ewesimyvcwmjptdwzbkqoasrcppe/Build/Products/Debug
 -filelist /Users/carl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/example-ewesimyvcwmjptdwzbkqoasrcppe/Build/Intermediates/example.build/Debug/example.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/example.LinkFileList
 -dependency_info /Users/carl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/example-ewesimyvcwmjptdwzbkqoasrcppe/Build/Intermediates/example.build/Debug/example.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/example_dependency_info.dat
 -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
 -F/Users/carl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/example-ewesimyvcwmjptdwzbkqoasrcppe/Build/Products/Debug
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found that field under Build Settings > Linking and added "-v", but no joy.

Comment: Or rather I should say it gives me a lot more (not apparently helpful) information and still gives the same clang error message (as if I hadn't invoked `-v`).

Comment: I just made a test here and got the linker invocation; maybe something is different in your case.

Comment: @JohnK does that 'not apparently helpful' info include the linker invocation?